# Проблема с обработчиком нажатия в viewpager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Здравствуй друг. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть обработчик нажатия во фрагменте, при активации которого вылетает ошибка.

Код фрагмента:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    EditText dateBox, clientBox, docBox, orderBox, noteBox, timeBox;
    DatabaseHelper sqlHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;
    long userID = 0;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment1, container, false);
        

        dateBox = view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        docBox = view.findViewById(R.id.document);
        clientBox = view.findViewById(R.id.client);
        timeBox = view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        orderBox = view.findViewById(R.id.order);
        noteBox = view.findViewById(R.id.note);


        Button but = view.findViewById(R.id.saveBut);
        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DATE, dateBox.getText().toString());
                cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CL, clientBox.getText().toString());
                cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DOC, docBox.getText().toString());
                cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TIME, timeBox.getText().toString());
                cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ORDER, orderBox.getText().toString());
                cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NOTE, noteBox.getText().toString());

                if (userID > 0) {
                    db.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, cv, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(userID), null);
                } else {
                    db.insertOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null, cv);
                }
            }
        });

        Intent intent= new Intent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            userID = bundle.getLong("id");
        }

        if (userID > 0) {
            userCursor = db.rawQuery(" select * from "
                            + DatabaseHelper.TABLE
                            + " where "
                            + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID
                            + " =? ",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(userID)});
            userCursor.moveToFirst();

            dateBox.setText(userCursor.getString(3));
            clientBox.setText(userCursor.getString(1));
            docBox.setText(userCursor.getString(4));
            timeBox.setText(userCursor.getString(5));
            orderBox.setText(userCursor.getString(2));
            noteBox.setText(userCursor.getString(6));

            userCursor.close();
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
03-12 09:48:46.970 4191-4191/com.example.application E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.application, PID: 4191
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.application.Fragment1$3.onClick(Fragment1.java:75)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-12 09:48:47.032 1674-1956/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
03-12 09:48:47.032 1674-1956/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По видимому вы забыли инициализировать базу

```
sqlHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
db = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DATE, dateBox.getText().toString());
cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CL, clientBox.getText().toString());
cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DOC, docBox.getText().toString());
cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TIME, timeBox.getText().toString());
cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ORDER, orderBox.getText().toString());
cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NOTE, noteBox.getText().toString());
if (userID > 0) {
       db.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, cv, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(userID), null);
} else {
       db.insertOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null, cv);
}
db.close();
sqlHelper.close();
```

Comment: Ой, а Вы правы, немного невнимателен )